# recover corrupted directory from ext3 partition

Tags: data-recovery, ext3, corruption

It's my mounted directory that I want to restore folder `ostani`. It contains many PHP, CSS, Javascript, etc. files. How can I access it? I use `dd_rhelper` to create an image and tried to `fsck` to repair it. But it's remove corrupted folder.

```
root@asgharserver:~# ls -la /root/oldhard/
ls: /root/oldhard/bina: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /root/oldhard/ostani: Input/output error
total 1187011436
drwxr-xr-x  26 root      root            4096 Jan  3 00:56 .
drwx------   4 root      root            4096 Jan 11 12:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2      1007      1007       4096 Aug 19 14:14 afshin
?--------- 512       512  33554432 2256582144 Jan 24  1971 bina
drwxr-xr-x   6 superuser superuser       4096 Nov 15 07:15 mahalleha
d?????????   ? ?         ?                  ?            ? ostani
drwxr-xr-x   2      1012      1012       4096 Aug 26 08:15 tvasr
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the inode information for the `ostani` dir is corrupted. However, the actual data might be just fine.

If so, you can use debugfs to recover this. Unmount the hard drive and proceed.

```
debugfs -c /dev/sdNP     #  replace N and P with the hard disk letter and partition
                         #  the -c option opens the filesystem in read-only mode without looking for inode information

# At the debugfs prompt do the following
ls -l                    #  this lists down the dir/file
rdump ostani  /tmp       #  this saves the recovered data of ostani dir to /tmp/ostani
```

Comment: ty but i cant find any file in ostani. check output. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1521226/

Comment: You are not doing it correctly. From inside of `debugfs` you cannot `cd` into a directory as debugfs sees that as a file with directory entry.
Once you are inside debugfs, just run `rdump ostani /destination/dir/`. All of the contents, along with `ostani` directory will be restored as it is recursive in nature.

Comment: i do that's also check my paste. `debugfs:  rdump ostani /home/backup/` line `5`. it's not work after press enter nothing happened and show me new entry line. without any load and process time.